# What's the best data type for DATE and TIME in MySQL database to display time RELATIVE to the user?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time, datetime-format

[image]

For instance, I have a blog where users can comment and I want everyone can see how *long ago* the comment was posted, for example: *5 minutes ago* OR *3 hours ago*.

So if a guy in London posts a comment and a guy in India visits the page, they both should see "*1 minute ago*" and on *hover* should see the time relative to their timezone. (10pm in London, 3.30am in India).

My current solution in mind is to use varchar(25) data type and store the time as ISO-8601 (e.g. 2019-12-12T21:46:42+00:00)

Using this I can get the timezone of the commenter and convert the time to the current user's timezone. It works perfectly.

But I wonder if there is a **better / more elegant** way to do it?

So far I tried using DATETIME and TIMESTAMP data types but they do not seem to be useful in this scenario. I read online that TIMESTAMP is supposed to store time in UTC timezone and send it back in user's timezone but that did not happen for me, it got saved in my local time instead. And yes, I did not specify any time while saving data, MySQL used the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

[image]

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Interesting blog by Jon Skeet. [STORING UTC IS NOT A SILVER BULLET](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/)

Comment: Whatever you do, do not use VARCHAR for dates. Best to use datetime

Comment: What's the problem in storing the time as usual as a timestamp? Why should the database itself know about the timezone of any user? Everything else happens in your application, and only that application converts this time to the timezone of the logged in user

Comment: @NicoHaase For some reason, using timestamp the time was saving in my local timezone and not in UTC, which wasn't useful at all. I read online it is supposed to be saving time in UTC but for me, that didn't happen. Not sure why.

Comment: "Not sure why" sounds like you want to share some code?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm sure you know this. To save time in timestamp format, you do not really need to code (at least not in PHP which is what I'm using). MySQL fills your timestamp column automatically when you insert a record.

Comment: @RehanAdil MySQL won’t randomly fill any column - only if you define it that way. And if you want to know why that could have gone wrong, you should share details about this such that others can find an explanation about why the time was stored in your local timezone and not using UTC

Comment: @NicoHaase Okay, so the code I have has no mention of time as of now because MySQL filled in the timestamp automatically so far and it did it in my local timezone (GMT +6) instead of UTC. And I just added an image in the original description of the timestamp column's attributes and so on. Also just added the code just for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend storing all your dates/times in one universal format in your database and UTC would be the best candidate for this.

That way, regardless of their location, it's easy for you to say 1 minute ago...

If you need to display the full date/time on the front-end, you'd need to convert the time from UTC to that user's location, which you can do via PHP's handy DateTime functions:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: This is great! With this I can use DATETIME data type and do calculations within MySQL. Awesome. Thanks!